# ASP.NET Core / EF Core 6: dbContext.saveChanges() produces stack overflow error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Getting "stack overflow" error when saving data to `dbContext.saveChanges()`

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 87208 times:
--------------------------------
   at WebAPI.Models.WorkProfile..ctor()
   at WebAPI.Models.WorkAccount..ctor()
--------------------------------
   at DynamicClass..ctor()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryRead(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader ByRef, System.Type, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.ReadStack ByRef, System.__Canon ByRef)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryRead(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader ByRef, System.Type, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.ReadStack ByRef, System.__Canon ByRef)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.ReadStack ByRef)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCoreAsObject(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader ByRef, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.ReadStack ByRef)
etc. 
etc. 
etc..........
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult<WorkAccount>> Post(WorkAccount workAccount)
{
    if (Request.HasJsonContentType())
    {
        // this runs: logs out JSONcontent.
        Console.WriteLine("JSON content");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NO json!");
    }

    _context.WorkAccounts.Add(workAccount);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetTodoItem", workAccount);
}
```

And these are my model classes:

```cs
public class WorkAccount : BaseDateEntity
{
    public int WorkAccountId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public WorkProfile? WorkProfile { get; set; } = new WorkProfile();
}

public class WorkProfile : BaseDateEntity
{
    public int WorkProfileId { get; set; }
    public int WorkAccountId { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } = new List<Booking>();
    public List<Advert> Adverts { get; set; } = new List<Advert>();
    public List<WorkProfileLanguage> WorkProfileLanguages { get; set; } = new List<WorkProfileLanguage>();
    public WorkAccount WorkAccount { get; set; } = new WorkAccount();
}

// and some more models...
```

FluentAPI configuration

```cs
public class WorkAccountConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<WorkAccount>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<WorkAccount> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
        .HasOne(x => x.WorkProfile)
        .WithOne(y => y.WorkAccount)
        .HasForeignKey<WorkProfile>(z => z.WorkAccountId);
    }
}
```

Before this error, I had an another error. My WorkProfile navigation property looked like: `public WorkProfile? WorkProfile { get; set; }` without the `= new WorkProfile()` initialization and that produced the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have also tried just returning the JSON data and it produces no errors and valid json.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<WorkAccount>> Post(WorkAccount workAccount)
{
    return workAccount;
}
```

The console.log output at chrome developer tools.

```
{
    "workAccountId": 0,
    "email": "mail here",
    "password": "boo",
    "workProfile": null,
    "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

I am stuck. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: If WorkProfile creates an instance of a WorkAccount, and WorkAccount creates an instance of a WorkProfile, and WorkProfile creates an instance of a WorkAccount, and WorkAccount creates an instance of a WorkProfile, and WorkProfile creates an instance of a WorkAccount, and WorkAccount creates an instance of a WorkProfile, and WorkProfile creates an instance of a WorkAccount, and WorkAccount creates an instance of a WorkProfile, and WorkProfile creates an instance of a WorkAccount, and WorkAccount creates an instance of a WorkProfile, and WorkProfile creates an instance...see where this leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time either `WorkAccount` or `WorkProfile` is instantiated you will create an infinite loop because `WorkAccount` creates a new default `WorkProfile` which creates a new default `WorkAccount` which creates a new `WorkProfile`

I would suggest removing those default instances.

You can get this same behavior just by trying to instantiate one of these.

```
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var w = new WorkAccount();
        }

        public class WorkAccount 
        {
            public int WorkAccountId { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public WorkProfile? WorkProfile { get; set; } = new WorkProfile();
        }

        public class WorkProfile 
        {
            public int WorkProfileId { get; set; }
            public int WorkAccountId { get; set; }
            public WorkAccount WorkAccount { get; set; } = new WorkAccount();
        }

    }
```

The above will result in

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 130975 times:
--------------------------------
   at Program+WorkProfile..ctor()
   at Program+WorkAccount..ctor()
--------------------------------
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

Removing the default instances runs without issue.

```
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var w = new WorkAccount();
        }

        public class WorkAccount 
        {
            public int WorkAccountId { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public WorkProfile? WorkProfile { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkProfile 
        {
            public int WorkProfileId { get; set; }
            public int WorkAccountId { get; set; }
            public WorkAccount WorkAccount { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: But how do you get rid of the System.NullReferenceException error when I remove the navigation property?

Comment: @J.Reku You haven't demonstrated any NullReferenceException to us. Sounds like a different question if you can't figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: Without knowing what code is causing that error, my guess is that you didn't set up the [Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) properly.

Comment: @mason I did state the nullReferenceException in my post, it is produced when I remove the instantiation of the WorkAccount/WorkProfile fields. I didn't know which one of the two errors was most fitting as I am new to asp.net core. But having two errors in one question might not be the right thing. I will have to create a new question for the other error.

Comment: I would suggest a new question with details about the null reference error.  Exactly where it occurs, etc.